# Ubuntu server not allowing domain to access laravel project [405]

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, azure, domain, ufw

I have a problem where my laravel project is accessed by my static IP on Azure but not from the domain that I linked it with:

I use nginx and ufw

This is the error.log for my Nginx:

```
nginx configuration 
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name domain;
    root /var/www/app/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

What should I do? what rule should I add?

````
2022/05/19 11:25:42 [error] 586486#586486: *1562 access forbidden by rule, client: 51.79.29.48, server: domain, request: "GET /.env HTTP/1.1", host: "ip"
2022/05/19 11:32:22 [error] 586486#586486: *1563 access forbidden by rule, client: 69.162.243.124, server: domain, request: "GET /.env HTTP/1.1", host: "ip"
2022/05/19 11:45:07 [error] 586486#586486: *1604 access forbidden by rule, client: 185.254.196.223, server: domain, request: "GET /.env HTTP/1.1", host: "ip"
2022/05/19 12:38:43 [notice] 600838#600838: signal process started```

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp (OpenSSH)           ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80/tcp (Nginx HTTP)        ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22/tcp (OpenSSH (v6))      ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (Nginx HTTP (v6))   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
````

Comment: This isn't related to firewall, looks like some location denying access to hidden files, e.g. `location /. { deny all; }`

Comment: @IvanShatsky I removed it and restarted nginx and still the same problem

Comment: Please provide your nginx configuration. We can't guess.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider done

Comment: I just noticed: The log entries only mention `/.env`. Are you sure you want to make your .env file publicly available? This seems like a pretty good precaution to prevent leaks of your configuration.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider how can I make it private if you can help me?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. I'm just wondering if you actually have a problem with your server configuration or if you only think you do.

Comment: I don't want to make it public and that's why I need help because I don't know why it's not hitting the routes themselves while it works fine when I access it by its IP @GeraldSchneider

Answer (score 1):

You should add all the index files in your configuration,

```
sudo nano etc/nginx/sites-enabled

index index.php index.html index.hml;
```

And the configuration should be like this:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name server_domain_or_IP;
root /var/www/app/public;

add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

index index.html index.htm index.php;

charset utf-8;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

error_page 404 /index.php;

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
    deny all;
}
}
```

To confirm that your configuration doesn’t contain any syntax errors, use

```
sudo nginx -t
```

Note: If you are maintaining a firewall from your console then don't use ufw to allow port.